# Need to get a mysql query tunned

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, mysql-5.7

I have a MySQL query which is taking more then 6 days for completion with around 250 million records in activation_member table and around 1.9 million records in temp_message_split table. Looking for help in tunning this query:

```
UPDATE TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT A,
                            (SELECT

                                            ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY,
                                            dh_member_id,
                                            alt_id,
                                            drsn
                            FROM ACTIVATION_MEMBER AM )  B  
                            SET A.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY = B.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY, A.STATUS = 'U'
                            WHERE  A.DH_MEMBER_ID = B.DH_MEMBER_ID OR ( (A.ALT_ID = b.alt_id) AND (A.DRSN = b.drsn)) ;
```

The update query is meant for updating the TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT.STATUS = 'U' in TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT table for all the members which are already present in activation_member table. We need to optimize this query so that it will take as min. time as possible for execution.

Table create statements:

```
  CREATE TABLE
activation_member
(
    ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY bigint,
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    DOB DATE,
    EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR(20),
    CES_CUST_NUM VARCHAR(7),
    MED_POLICY_NUM VARCHAR(20),
    EMAIL_ADDR VARCHAR(50),
    DH_MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(9),
    ALT_ID VARCHAR(20),
    DRSN VARCHAR(2),
    SSN VARCHAR(9),
    EPIPHANY_MEMBER_ID bigint,
    SYSTEM_HIS_CNT mediumint,
    SYSTEM_USER VARCHAR(30),
    SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY),
    CONSTRAINT ACTIVATION_MEMBER_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY) REFERENCES
    `portal_statement_loc` (`PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY`),
    INDEX ACTIVATION_MEMBER_IDX1 (PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY),
    INDEX ACTIVATION_MEMBER_IDX2 (DH_MEMBER_ID),
    INDEX ACTIVATION_MEMBER_IDX3 (EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, MED_POLICY_NUM, DOB),
    INDEX ACTIVATION_MEMBER_IDX4 (EPIPHANY_MEMBER_ID),
    INDEX ACTIVATION_MEMBER_IDX5 (ALT_ID, DRSN)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE
portal_statement_loc
(
    PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PORTAL_ADDRESS VARCHAR(200),
    STATEMENT_VENDOR VARCHAR(100),
    SYSTEM_HIS_CNT mediumint,
    SYSTEM_USER VARCHAR(30),
    SYSTEM_TIMESTAMP DATETIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

CREATE TABLE
temp_message_split
(
    FIRST_NAME VARCHAR(20),
    LAST_NAME VARCHAR(30),
    DOB VARCHAR(10),
    EMPLOYEE_ID VARCHAR(20),
    CES_CUST_NUM VARCHAR(7),
    MED_POLICY_NUM VARCHAR(20),
    EMAIL_ADDR VARCHAR(50),
    DH_MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(9),
    ALT_ID VARCHAR(20),
    DRSN VARCHAR(2),
    SSN VARCHAR(9),
    EPIPHANY_MEMBER_ID VARCHAR(18),
    PORTAL_ADDRESS VARCHAR(30),
    STATEMENT_VENDOR VARCHAR(20),
    CONTENT_KEY VARCHAR(18),
    EPIPHANY_COMMUNICATION_ID VARCHAR(200),
    PRIORITY VARCHAR(4),
    DAYS_UNTIL_EXPIRED VARCHAR(4),
    CONTENT_DTL_KEY VARCHAR(18),
    STATUS VARCHAR(1),
    ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY bigint,
    MESSAGE_BOARD_KEY bigint,
    PORTAL_STATEMENT_LOC_KEY bigint,
    temp_message_split_KEY bigint NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    PRIMARY KEY (temp_message_split_KEY),
    INDEX EPIPHANY_COMMUNICATION_ID_IDX (EPIPHANY_COMMUNICATION_ID),
    INDEX TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT_IDX1 (DH_MEMBER_ID),
    INDEX TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT_IDX2 (ALT_ID),
    INDEX TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT_IDX3 (DRSN)
)
ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. We're here to help other coders when they get stuck. If you want help, you'll need to provide relevant information. Not sure what measurement * **lacs** * is, but if you have a query that takes 6 days to complete with only two tables with 25 rows and 19 rows, you have some serious hardware / OS issues.

Comment: @sloanthrasher it's 100000. Crore is 10m

Comment: As well as SHOW CREATE TABLE statements for all relevant tables, questions about query performance always require the EXPLAIN for the given query

Comment: 25 crore is 250 million and 19 lacs is 1.9 million and also I edited my question to add table create statements and explanation of query.

Comment: I don't see the results of the EXPLAIN for the query...

Answer (score 0):

- Use a multi-table `UPDATE` `JOIN` without a subquery (if possible).
- Please use the `JOIN ... ON` syntax instead of the old "commajoin" syntax.
- Instead of using `OR`, do two `UPDATEs`.  *If* we can devise adequate indexes for the query, then each update will run a lot faster.

This *might* be the correct syntax:

```
UPDATE  TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT A
    JOIN  ACTIVATION_MEMBER AM  ON A.DH_MEMBER_ID = B.DH_MEMBER_ID
                              AND  A.ALT_ID = b.alt_id
    SET A.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY = B.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY,
        A.STATUS = 'U';

UPDATE  TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT A
    JOIN  ACTIVATION_MEMBER AM  ON A.DH_MEMBER_ID = B.DH_MEMBER_ID
                              AND  A.DRSN = b.drsn
    SET A.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY = B.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY,
        A.STATUS = 'U';
```

and this for one of the tables (or add to both tables, since I don't know if one table would be preferred):

```
INDEX(dh_member_id, alt_id)  -- in either order
INDEX(dh_member_id, dsrn)    -- in either order
```

The processing will have to scan one table entirely, then reach ("Nested Loop Join") into the other.

`UPDATE` (or `DELETE`) of a large number of rows can take a long time because of saving the rows for undo-ing in case of a crash or `ROLLBACK`.  One thing to consider doing is to do the `UPDATEs` in chunks of, say, 1000 rows at a time.  [*This*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/deletebig#deleting_in_chunks) discusses how to do that efficiently.

Comment: but, how this serves the purpose of "or". In my query, WHERE  A.DH_MEMBER_ID = B.DH_MEMBER_ID OR ( (A.ALT_ID = b.alt_id) AND (A.DRSN = b.drsn)), my query means either DH_MEMBER_ID are equal in both tables or (ALT_ID and drsn) together are equal in both tables.

Comment: @Parul - Oops.  I'll leave the rewriting of the one `UPDATE` into two, splitting on the `OR` as an exercise to the reader.  (And check that you already had optimal indexes.)

Answer (score 0):

I think the correct updates would be:

```
 UPDATE  TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT A
JOIN  ACTIVATION_MEMBER B  ON A.DH_MEMBER_ID = B.DH_MEMBER_ID
SET A.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY = B.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY,
    A.STATUS = 'U';

   UPDATE  TEMP_MESSAGE_SPLIT A
JOIN  ACTIVATION_MEMBER B  ON A.ALT_ID = B.ALT_ID AND A.DRSN = B.DRSN
SET A.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY = B.ACTIVATION_MEMBER_KEY,
    A.STATUS = 'U';
```